# How to change the opacity on an element dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, opacity

i made a function that change the opacity of an element, but you know it is not working, Following is my code:

```
   function _opacity(ele, opacity,addOpac , delay ){
    ele = document.getElementById(ele);
    var CurrentOpacity = ele.style.opacity,
        ChangeInOpacity = setInterval(function(){
            if (CurrentOpacity > opacity ) { decrease();};
            if (CurrentOpacity < opacity) { increase();};
            if (CurrentOpacity == opacity) { stopInc();};

            }, delay),

        increase = function(){
            ele.style.opacity = CurrentOpacity;
            CurrentOpacity = CurrentOpacity+addOpac;
        },

        decrease =function(){
            ele.style.opacity = CurrentOpacity;
            CurrentOpacity = CurrentOpacity-addOpac;

        },
        stopInc = function(){
            clearInterval(ChangeInOpacity);
        };
}
```

one of the foremost feature of this function is that is doesn't uses any loop.

this ideology of using `setInterval` works perfectly in changing the width and height of element. But here this function is not functioning.

What i know is that it is not adding any style attribute to the element which is passed to the above function

what is the mistake here because of which this is not working?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you add or subtract `addOpac` _before_ you assign the style?

Comment: thanks.. but how did this simple solution made this function worked???

Comment: Does the element actually have an opacity style applied to it? `ele.style` only accesses inline styles, not styles from CSS.

Comment: Do you realize that the `style.opacity` value is a string, not a number.  It also might not initially be present at all until you set it.

Comment: and you can post this comment as answer  and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems there:

1. To get the current opacity of the element, you need to use the `getComputedStyle` function (or `currentStyle` property on oldIE), not `.style.opacity`. The latter only has a value if it's been assigned explicitly, rather than implicitly through style sheets.
2. The value will be a string, so you need to convert it to a number.
3. It's unlikely that you'll **exactly** match the target opaccity, so you need to just stop when you cross the target.
4. You don't put `;` at the end of `if` statements, so remove those.
5. You assign the opacity, but then increment it, and then later the incremented value is what you check to see if you're done, so even if it weren't for #3, you'd stop early.
6. In JavaScript, the *overwhelming* convention is to start local variable names with a lower-case letter. I changed the name of your timer handle to `timer`.

Your best bet is to figure out what direction you're going, then stop when you pass the target:

```js
// Polyfill getComputedStyle for old IE
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
  window.getComputedStyle = function(element) {
    return element.currentStyle;
  }
}

// Your _opacity function
function _opacity(ele, opacity, addOpac, delay) {
  var direction;
  ele = document.getElementById(ele);
  
  // Determine direction
  direction = +getComputedStyle(ele).opacity < opacity ? 1 : -1;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Get the *computed* opacity
    var current = +getComputedStyle(ele).opacity;
    if (direction > 0) {
      if (current < opacity) {
        increase(current);
      } else {
        stopInc();
      }
    }
    else {
      if (current > opacity) {
        decrease(current);
      } else {
        stopInc();
      }
    }

  }, delay),

  increase = function(current) {
    // Increase, but don't go past target
    ele.style.opacity = Math.min(current + addOpac, opacity);
  },

  decrease = function(current) {
        
    // Decrease, but don't go past target
    ele.style.opacity = Math.max(current - addOpac, opacity);

  },
  stopInc = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
};

// Run
_opacity("target", 0.3, 0.05, 50);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div id="target">this is the element</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
ele.style.opacity = "0.2";// some desired value but string if for all browsers.
```

for more info see this post:[Setting opacity of html elements in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539713/setting-opacity-of-html-elements-in-different-browsers)