# how to change the opaqueness of a colored box by click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, opacity

I have a homework to make a box fade which means to click a button to change the opacity of a colored box. but I couldn't make it work. below are some coding. what is wrong? thanks a lot.

```
<button id="button3">Fade</button>

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.Opacity = "0.5";
});
```

Comment: Hint: JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting opacity of html elements in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539713/setting-opacity-of-html-elements-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problems

1. you are trying to access an element with `id` of `box`
2. As [heretic monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910876/how-to-change-the-opaqueness-of-a-colored-box-by-click-a-button#comment98476954_55910876) said, javascript is case-sensitive, meaning `Opacity` should be `opacity`

### Fixing the above

```js
document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("button3").style.opacity = "0.5";
});
```

```html
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
```

### More reading

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

> **Note:** JavaScript is case sensitive — myVariable is a different variable to myvariable. If you are getting problems in your code, check the casing!

Comment: accepted. am I doing it right? this is my first time.

Comment: @utbc2019 click the checkmark below the score to the left of my answer